# Numbers to string and vice versa in PHP

Tags: php

How do I convert numbers to a string and vice versa in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Numbers to string: just use it like a string and it is a string, or explicitly cast.

```
$number = 1234;
echo "the number is $number";
$string = (string) $number;
$otherString = "$number";
```

2) Strings to number: use a c-style cast.

```
$string = "1234";
$int = (int) $string;
$float = (float) $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP is dynamically typed and will evaluate which scalar type to use depending on the context. You just have to be aware how this happens. See the PHP manual on

- [Type Juggling](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

> PHP does not require (or support) explicit type definition in variable declaration; a variable's type is determined by the context in which the variable is used. That is to say, if a string value is assigned to variable $var, $var becomes a string . If an integer value is then assigned to $var, it becomes an integer .

- [String conversion to numbers](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

> If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E' and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer . In all other cases it will be evaluated as a float .

- [Converting to string](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting)

> A value can be converted to a string using the (string) cast or the strval()  function. String conversion is automatically done in the scope of an expression where a string is needed. This happens when using the echo()  or print()  functions, or when a variable is compared to a string . The sections on Types and Type Juggling will make the following clearer. See also the settype() function.

Answer (score 0):

There are functions like [`intval`](http://php.net/intval) and [`floatval`](http://php.net/floatval) to parse number strings. And for number to string conversion, just use an explicit [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) using `(string)` or implicitly via string concatenation.